# How to organize Kotlin extension methods

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Let's say I have a few extension methods for "MyClass".
My question is, what's the best practice to organize/store these methods?
Should they be simply put into a "MyClassExtensions" Kotlin file?

I have tried to encapsulate these methods within a class, but after importing the class I couldn't seem to figure out how to use/access the extension methods.

Edit:
For clarification, I was not asking for help what to call a file that contains extension methods. I was asking about best practices/approaches to store/organize such methods. Ie. should they be simply put into kotlin files, or should they be encapsulated in a class. I am coming from a Java background, so I'm used to store stuff in classes.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#scope-of-extensions

Comment: Thanks, I must have accidentally missed this part in the docs.

Comment: `best practices/approaches to store/organize such methods` that makes this question very opinion based

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, you should put them into a utility file, as you did in Java code base before.

But mention, you no longer need to put them into a class. Top-level functions are the best choice.

You can refer to the kotlin standard library or some open source projects like [anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/), those would be good examples.

In my case, I put extensions of one class into a file which have the same name of the original file in another package, and use

```
@JvmMultifileClass
```

to reduce the number of generated class files.